# Failing to load my Global Planner

Tags: ros, base-global-planner, plugin, global-planner, nav-core

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Guys,

I am following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) to write my own global planner.
Everything seems to work fine and I can see my plugin, when I call:

rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nav_core

but if I want to use it I keep getting this error:

Failed to create the dijkstra_planner/DijkstraPlanner planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type dijkstra_planer::DijkstraPlanner as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()

Could this have something to do with my ROS version? I am using indigo und not hydro like in the tutorial.

I would be very thankful if anybody could help me.

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239439/failing-to-load-my-global-planner/) by [Earthgrazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27252/earthgrazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That usually happens when you don't call `PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS`. Do you have the appropriate call to `PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS` at the end of the source code for your plugin?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Earthgrazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/27252/earthgrazer/) on 2016-07-18**:
Yes, I do, it is at the beginning of my source code like in the tutorial.

**Comment by [cgm666](https://answers.ros.org/users/71636/cgm666/) on 2021-03-08**:
Hi, did you solve this problem? I also meet it:(